# Vaadin testing filter with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, filter, vaadin

I am currently struggling with my JUnit test. I thought that the Vaadin table would simply mark those entries which don't match the filter as invisible. So I was thinking I could make a test to test my filter, by applying a filter to a table and then checking the table.getVisibleItemIds();. But even though I tried a few things it still returns an empty list. My goal is to compare which Items were returned by the filter.

```
Table table = new Table();
IndexedContainer indexedContainer = new IndexedContainer();
table.setContainerDataSource(indexedContainer);
table.addContainerProperty(TableColumns.NAME, String.class, " ");
table.setColumnHeader(TableColumns.NAME, "name");
this.addTestDataToTable(table);
TableSearchFilter filter = new TableSearchFilter(searchString);
indexedContainer.addContainerFilter(filter);
return table.getVisibleItemIds();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Vaadin container "contains" only the item currently filtered, ordered and so on.

```
.getVisibleItemsIds()
```

refers to actually VISIBLE, like with eyes, rows: is and old legacy method and you should avoit it if your really intent is to know which rows are really seeable. You get null/empty because on your test you never attach your Table, hence is not really "visible" or has zero-size.

So back on your problem the solution is just

```
.getItemIds()
```

and you'll get all the ids of the items in the container already filtered and ordered.

Cheers